# Synchronized Database Access

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I am using database in my application, I have requirement to access database synchronously, for example when my application starts two threads are accessing the database, how can I avoid  this situation?

```
private synchronized Database accessDB()
{
    Database dbObj = null;
    try {
_uri = URI.create(dbLocation + DB_NAME);
try {
dbObj = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(_uri, new DatabaseSecurityOptions(false)); 
System.out.println("Database Created"+_dbTopNews);
    } catch (ControlledAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (DatabaseIOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DatabasePathException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURIException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dbObj;
}
```

te above method when debugging returns object to first thread, but it is returning null when  second thread is accessed

A Y

Comment: For the next time: No need for capslock in the title.

Comment: Thomas Jungblut, thanks a lot buddy, one thing I should keep in my mind is NO CAPS LOCK :D

Answer (score 3):

Generally, there are two ways to do this, depending on which isolation you are after.

1: Transactions. This isolates operations in the database. Guaranteeing, for instance, that only one thread (session) at a time can make changes to a table or a row.

2: Synchronization. This is the method in Java by which thread concurrency is handled in a multithreaded environment. By using synchronization (and "locking"), sections of your code can be isolated so that only one thread at a time may execute it.

Hard to be more specific with the information you provided.

Comment: thanks for the answer pap, that was of great help, I must apologize for the nature of my explanation, I am working on this for first time, so not able to put it properly from my perspective, I am trying to implement synchronization for accessing database object.

Comment: I have 2 threads, thread 1 and thread2. Thread1 parses a xml and openorcreate new DATABASE1, create and inserts in a table1 and thread2 openorcreate DATABASE1 and inserts in a table2.

Comment: If your threads are inserting into different tables, maybe you don't need to synchronize

Comment: I edited the above question to share my code, please look check it if I am making any mistake

Comment: pap, I am facing problem when creating an object for database access, thread1 is getting object to access while thread2 is getting null..

Comment: Does DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate return null or are you getting an exception? I haven't developed anything on the blackberry, so I'm not sure how that thing works.